How to access QWidgets from page controller class?
I am developing a database software using PyQt6 and SQlite3. I am struggling a bit in organising the files and classes since this is my first project of such. I have kept the main.py in the root to open the window, and I have various stacked widgets like home_page, dashboard_page etc. Every such page has various QWidgets (pushbutton, combobox etc). In order to separate the task inside the controller folder I have files for each stacked page that defines tasks for each widget in the respective pages. So I have the following directory:
root_directory/
│
├── main.py
│
├── ui/
│   ├── ui_main.py
│   └── ui_functions.py
│
└── controller/
    ├── home_page_controller.py
    └── (other_controller_files.py)

In the main file I have created a MainWindow class which is an instance of QMainWindow, and initialized the UI components:
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)

        # SET AS GLOBAL WIDGETS
        # ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        global widgets
        widgets = self.ui

Then I tried creating HomePageController class in homepage_controller.py. Here is the code:
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QFileDialog

class HomePageController:
    def __init__(self, Ui_MainWindow):
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow

        # Connect buttons to functions
        self.ui.open_db_btn_homepage.clicked.connect(self.open_db)
        self.ui.create_new_db_btn_homepage.clicked.connect(self.create_new_db)
        

    def open_db(self):
        file_name, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self.ui, "Open database file", "", "All Files (*)")
        if file_name:
            print(file_name)

But this way I am unable to access any widgets from HomePageCotroller class. As a result I am getting an error from QFileDialog:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\Python_workspace\app\controller\home_page_controller.py", line 14, in open_db
    file_name, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self.ui, "Open database file", "", "All Files (*)")
TypeError: getOpenFileName(parent: typing.Optional[QWidget] = None, caption: str = '', directory: str = '', filter: str = '', initialFilter: str = '', options: QFileDialog.Option = QFileDialog.Options()): argument 1 has unexpected type 'Ui_MainWindow'

To resolve I tried the following line in MainWindow class:
# Instantiate HomePageController with self as the parent widget
self.home_page_controller = HomePageController(self.ui)


Ui_MainWindow is a "form class" generated by pyuic; it's just a standard python object class used as a helper to setup the ui, so it's not a widget, which is what functions like getOpenFileName() expect as a parent. You should almost never use the ui instance alone (if one is created) externally. See the official guidelines about using Designer.

Try importing 2 classes at the same time and pass the self object directly to QFileDialog, not the ui object.
class MainWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.open_db_btn_homepage.clicked.connect(self.open_db)

    def open_db(self):
        file_name, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, "Open database file", "", "All Files (*)")
        if file_name:
            print(file_name)


I am trying to define all the widgets tasks in the controller class, instead of MainWindow class.

@BobWallace There's little point in doing it. Widgets are part of the window, so they should also be members of its instance (even using composition, eg. through self.ui), having two separate objects that are so intrinsically related is inappropriate. What x0smic suggests is the most common, suggested and appropriate way of using pyuic based classes. Don't fixate too much in strictly following MVC pattern, but properly consider object structure and hierarchy. Even assuming you do need a controller (which is rarely the case for simple apps), access the widgets through the window instance.

I was able to solve the issue in the following way, but not sure if it's the most efficient method.
class HomePageController(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, MainWindow):
        super().__init__()
        self.main_window = MainWindow.ui

        # Connect buttons to functions
        self.main_window.open_db_btn_homepage.clicked.connect(self.open_db)

    def open_db(self):
        file_name, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, "Open database file", "", "All Files (*)")
        if file_name:
           print(file_name)


The problem is not inefficiency, but wrong context and its usage. The code above "works" just because you've defined HomePageController as a QWidget subclass, therefore the self in getOpenFileName() becomes a valid argument. But you're never going to actually show the HomePageController instance, so it would be fundamentally identical as using None instead of self. At the very least, it should be the QMainWindow instance (not the UI class/instance), but the point remains: if you don't intend to use HomePageController as an actual widget, you should not subclass from QWidget.
